# Cross compiling GLIBC for arm error: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

Whenever I call glibc configure with 
`--prefix=/usr --with-headers=/var/tmp/ubuild.wandboard-armhf.build_dir/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include --host=armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi --enable-bind-now --disable-profile --without-gd --without-cvs --disable-multi-arch --enable-obsolete-rpc --enable-kernel=2.6.9 --enable-add-ons=nptl,libidn,/var/tmp/ubuild.wandboard-armhf.build_dir/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/tools/usr/src/glibc-ports`

I get the following config error
`checking for .preinit_array/.init_array/.fini_array support... no
configure: error: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support.`

I'm using the following versions.

- Glibc 2.16
- GlibC-ports 2.16
- gcc 4.73
- binutils 2.23.1
- mpfr 2.4.2
- gmp 4.3.2
- mpc 0.8.1
- glibc headers 2.16
- linux kernel headers 3.10.17.1

  on a 64-bit Ubuntu as host. What could be the problem?
  The complete output is [here](https://gist.github.com/efe86c50726df8bada8f)

Comment: what toolchain/ cross-compiler did you use?